# curl for multiple operations in a passworded site

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to login tumblr for some operations.  I'm not using tumblr api because there are some other limitations.

As referred to some other posts.  I using curl_init, then multiple curl_exec and close.  But it doesn't seem to work.  $result1 shows that I'm sucessfully login.  But $result2 is empty.

```
   $request_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'email'     => $tumblr_email,
        'password'  => $tumblr_password,
    )
);


$c1 = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/login');
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c1, CURL_COOKIEFILE, '');  
$result1 = curl_exec($c1);

curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tumblr.com/likes/page/2');
$result2 = curl_exec($c1);

curl_close($c1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$request_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'email'     => $tumblr_email,
        'password'  => $tumblr_password,
    )
);


$c1 = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/login');
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c1, CURL_COOKIEFILE, 'somefilename1.txt');  
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'somefilename1.txt');  
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);//No caching
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,1);
$result1 = curl_exec($c1);

curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tumblr.com/likes/page/2');
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c1, CURL_COOKIEFILE, 'somefilename1.txt');  
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'somefilename1.txt');  
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);//No caching
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($c1,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,1);
$result2 = curl_exec($c1);

curl_close($c1);
```

Check this , it will work , actually u should specify some filename to store cookies from the site , it may be used for some authentication